# Java Spring 404 API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, model-view-controller, spring-security

Main Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.backend.hostezza.repository", "com.example.backend.hostezza.entities" })
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class BackendHostezzaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {SpringApplication.run(BackendHostezzaApplication.class, args);}
}
```

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Backend-Hostezza</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Backend-Hostezza</name>
    <description>CTD - Proyecto Integrador - Equipo6</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>hostezza</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Security Configuration

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Jwt.JwtEntryPoint;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Jwt.JwtTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AppUserService appUserService;
    @Autowired
    JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authentication/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/bookings", "/bookings/product/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/categories/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/cities/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/features/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/policies/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/products/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

JWT Provider

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.AppUser;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class JwtProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);

    private SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private int expiration;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        AppUser appUser = (AppUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        claims.put("user_info",appUser);
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(appUser.getUsername())
                .addClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiration * 99999))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
           }

    public String getEmailFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Token formed incorrectly");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Token not supported");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Token expired");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Token empty");
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Signature failed");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

JWT Token FIlter

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.AppUserService;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JwtTokenFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    @Autowired
    AppUserService appUserService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String token = getToken(request);
            if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                String emailUser = jwtProvider.getEmailFromToken(token);
                UserDetails userDetails = appUserService.loadUserByUsername(emailUser);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                                null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                logger.info("Usuario con email: " + emailUser + " autenticado");
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Fallo en el metodo doFilterInternal " + e.getMessage());
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer "))
            return header.substring(7);
        return null;
    }
}
```

JWT EntryPoint

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JwtEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Failed on commence method");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "You are not authorized");
    }
}
```

UserService

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Entities.User;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Repository.UserRepository;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;


@Service
@Transactional

public class UserService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserService.class);
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User newUser(User user) {
        logger.debug("Saving user: " + user);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        logger.debug("Listando usuarios: ");
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User userByEmail(String email) {
        logger.debug("Buscando usuario con email: " + email);
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public Boolean existsUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.existsByEmail(email);
    }

}
```

User Repository

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface  UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);

    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

Authentication Controller

```
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Entities.Role;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Entities.User;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Jwt.JwtProvider;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Payload.LoginRequest;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Payload.LoginResponse;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Security.Payload.RegisterRequest;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Service.EmailSenderService;
import com.example.Backend.Hostezza.Service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@CrossOrigin (origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
public class AuthenticationControler {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    @Autowired
    EmailSenderService emailSender;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("invalid data");
        }
        if (userService.existsUserByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("this email has already been registered");
        }
        User user = new User(registerRequest.getName(),
                registerRequest.getSurname(),
                registerRequest.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()),
                ""enter image description here
                );
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setId(2L);
        user.setRole(role);
        userService.newUser(user);
        String registerBody = emailSender.styleRegisterBody(registerRequest.getName());
        emailSender.sendEmail(registerRequest.getEmail(), "You have registered succesfully",
                registerBody);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("User has been registered");
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        LoginResponse token = new LoginResponse(jwt);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I am trying to test my authentication API but I get a 404. I need to create a user so I can get a JWT token. But every time I try to access my API, I get a 404. It doesn't matter which API I sent a request; I always get a 404.

The only solution that I found was copying this in my main application, to evade the 401 error that
I used to get:

```
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

I think it has to do something with spring security "reconfiguring" my Intellij because when I start an older version of this same project, I get the same error with my API's even though I didn't create any classes that implement spring security.

Comment: Are you getting 401 or 404 because you mention both?

Comment: Spring Security does not adjust IntelliJ settings. The @ComponentScan in the main file seems like it might not be inclusive, please include a representation of the project's file structure. Please include a sample HTTP request that is returning a 404.

Comment: @voidvoid I am getting a 404 error now

Comment: @jzheaux Oh ok. Here is a link to my project structure. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/19OHbNq7NUnRdx49B7_dAtCTeroT18M-i/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @jzheaux My bad, here is a folder with the two things that you asked for. I should clarify that my HTTP request sample is from postman because my intellij terminal doesn't  bring any errors. (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SqGVy-bqn9lC5xOtw8ktdZngRP7HaX40?usp=sharing)